# using a div:title tag attribute instead of a:href attribute to toggle divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script that uses an a:href attribute tag to swap divs out. I'd like to instead use a div tag with the title attribute.

Working code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tabs div').hide();
    $('#tabs div:first').show();
    $('#tabs2 ul li:first').addClass('active');

    $('#tabs2 ul li a').click(function () {
        $('#tabs2 ul li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        var currentTab = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#tabs div').hide();
        $(currentTab).fadeIn(1000);
        return false;
    });
});
```

My attempt at using this with a div tag but is not working

```
<div id="tabs2">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="pc"><div class="tab-1" title="tab-1">text</div></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tabs div').hide();
    $('#tabs div:first').show();
    $('#tabs2 ul li:first').addClass('active');

    $('#tabs2 ul li div').click(function () {
        $('#tabs2 ul li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        var currentTab = $(this).attr('title');
        $('#tabs div').hide();
        $(currentTab).fadeIn(1000);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Not getting any errors but its not working for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the HTML you provided the `title` attribute is `tab-1`.
Thus when you obtain that value `currrentTab` will only contain text `tab-1`.

Add the `#` to select an element with the id of `tab-1`:

```
$('#' + currentTab).fadeIn(1000);
```

Or add the `.` to select an element with the class of `tab-1`:

```
$('.' + currentTab).fadeIn(1000);
```

Comment: Please add a tabindex attribute (`tabindex=1`) to those divs so that users who navigate via keyboard can focus on them!

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a '#' at the begining of your selector here:

```
$(currentTab).fadeIn(1000);
```

This is resulting in `$('tab-1')` when should be $`('#tab-1')`

I guess it works when you're using the `a[href]` attribute because you're probably using something like `href="#tab-1"`.

Comment: Im confused where the pound sign should go.  Should it be  $(# + currentTab).fadIn(1000);